# No match for operator << in std::cout

Tags: c++, vector, cout

I'm trying to print every element inside a vector like this:

```
vector<users>::iterator i;

for(i = userlist.begin(); i<userlist.end(); i++)
{
        cout << *i << "\n";
}
```

Then I'm getting an error like this:

```
no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::cout << (&i)->__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator* [with _Iterator = users*, _Container = std::vector<users, std::allocator<users> >]()'
```

Is it anything obvious I've missed?

Comment: Does `users` overload `operator<<`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you defined a function with this signature?:

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &, const users &);
```

It should **not** be a member function of users, although it may or may not be a friend, up to you.  The prototype should go in the header file of class users, and the body should go in the source(.cpp) file.  I have no idea how your users class is defined, or how you would want to format the output, but the function definition should look something like this:

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const users & U)
{
    os << U.some_data_members;
    os << U.and_or_some_member_functions();
    os << whatever;
    return os;
}
```

Comment: No, not sure where to define it. In the header of the user class?

Comment: @user: Put the prototype in the header, exactly as above.  But put the body in the source(.cpp) file.

Comment: Okey, I've now defined the prototype in the header, but not exactly sure how to build the function in the source file.

Also, I'm getting this error after I defined the prototype in the header:

`std::ostream& user::operator<<(std::ostream&, const user&)' must take exactly one argument`

Sorry, I'm new to C++.

Answer (score 2):

Once you've defined `std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &, user&);`, consider changing your code to use `std::copy` instead of a `for` loop:

```
// leaving off the `std::`, you're not using it for `cout`.
// 
copy(userlist.begin(), userlist.end(), ostream_iterator<user>(cout, "\n"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you defined stream operator for the users class?  If not, do so.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write an overload of `ostream::operator<<()` that takes a an instance of `users`, or write some conversion operator that will provide an auto-conversion from `user` to some type that one of the `operator<<()` versions knows about.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your own public function operator<< taking parameters of an ostream and a users:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, users&);
```

Sorry, is it `users` or `user`?

Comment: It's `users`, but I guess I'll change it, looks better with `user`.

But where do I define the function? In the header of the user class? And do I have to create a function inside the user class aswell?

Comment: You usually declare the function in the header just below the user class, and define it in the module file alongside the user member functions.