# ERROR: no match for 'operator<<" in 'std::cout

Tags: c++, cout

I realize this error is usually due to some syntax or type issues but I am not sure how to solve this problem. I think it may do with the type of findRt.

```
vector<triangle> findRightTriangles(unsigned long l, unsigned long h) {

<triangle> retval; // storage for return value.

triangle t;    
double what;

for(t.s1 = 3; t.s1 <= h; t.s1++) {
    for(t.s2 = t.s1; t.s2 <= h; t.s2++) {
        what = sqrt((t.s1*t.s1) + (t.s2*t.s2));
        t.s3 = static_cast<unsigned int>(what);
        if(((t.s1*t.s1)+(t.s2*t.s2)) != (t.s3*t.s3) 
            || t.s1+t.s2+t.s3 < l 
                || t.s1+t.s2+t.s3 > h) {
            continue;
        }
        else if(t.s1+t.s2+t.s3 <= h 
            && t.s1+t.s2+t.s3 >= l 
                && t.s1+t.s2 > t.s3 
                    && ((t.s1*t.s1)+(t.s2*t.s2)) == (t.s3*t.s3)) {
            retval.push_back(t);
        }
    }
}
return retval;
}

int main(){

unsigned long min, max;

cin >> min >> max;

    //Here is the problem:
cout << findRightTriangles(min, max) << endl;

return 0;
}
```

How to output the vector using cout?

Comment: What is `triangle`?  Does it have an overload for `operator<<`?

Comment: have you checked this out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707827/no-match-for-operator-in-stdcout

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Why the error?**
The compiler reports an error because there is no overloaded version of `<<` operator to handle the type `vector<triangle>` which your function `findRightTriangles()` returns.
`<<` is overloaded only for most of the built-in data types and not for custom classes.

**How to output the vector using cout?**
There are two ways:

**Solution 1:**
A two step procedure:

**Step1:** You will have to iterate through the vector and `cout` each contained `triangle`.

```
std::vector<triangle>::const_iterator iter= vec.begin();
for(iter; iter != vec.end(); ++iter)
{
    cout<<*iter; //This is what step 2 provides for
}
```

**Step 2:** You will have to **[overload `<<`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)** for the `triangle` class as well.

```
ostream& operator<<( ostream& os, const triangle &) {}
```

---

**Solution 2:**
One step Solution.
Alternately, You can overload `<<` for vector type itself:

```
ostream& operator<<( ostream& os, const vector<triangle>&)
{

}
```

I would personally prefer the Solution 1. It is more readable & Usually more often than not one would already have an overloaded `<<` for the vector type being used and it could be leveraged.

Answer (score 3):

Use an iterator http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/.

Example would be

```c
vector<triangle>::iterator it;

cout << "myvector contains:";
for ( it=myvector.begin() ; it < myvector.end(); it++ )
    cout << " " << *it;

cout << endl;

return 0;
```

This assumes you have an `operator<<` for the `triangle` type.

Answer (score 1):

For `cout` to be able to output your object you have to tell it how. One way is to overload the  `<<` operator:

```
ostream& operator<<( ostream& os, const vector<triangle>& vec ) {
    ...
    ... // here output to os the way you want it to
    os << ...
    return os;
}
```

Comment: Probably cheaper and just as easy to say `const vector<triangle>&`.

Comment: Yes! Just realized that! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to create an overloaded version of `operator<<` for `std::cout`.  It would look something like the following:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const vector<triangle>& triangles);
```

and at the end of the function, you simply do a `return out;` in order to return the `std::ostream` object `out` that was passed as the first argument (in your case that will be `std::cout`).

In other words, when you do

```
MyFoo object;
std::cout << object;
```

this is "syntactic sugar" for the following function call:

```
MyFoo object;
operator<<(std::cout, object);
```

and would call a version of `operator<<` that looked like:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const MyFoo& my_object);
```

If the above function was not defined, then you'd get an error like you're currently experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

Operator "<<" is not overloaded for the type triangle. Have you checked [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707827/no-match-for-operator-in-stdcout) out?